# I want get other app screen time on iOS 12 ,can anybody tell me use which private API

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I am working on one project and I want to get other application usage time. apple has launched iOS 12 and provides the new feature Screen Time. I want to know is there any way or API provided by Apple to get data from it.